# I want to loop through a string of numbers

Tags: python

I have a string containing numbers, eg =  '78 56 78 1 7 '. If i try to loop through the string, it give me eg[0] as 7 instead of 78. Pls which syntax can i use to acheive this

Comment: Why do you think that the **one** character at position 0 should be `"78"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first need to transform the string of decimal representations of numbers into a list of integers. Use `split` to go from a string to a list of decimal representations and `int` to transform the decimal representation of each of them into a Python integer object.

```
>>> [int(_) for _ in '78 56 78 1 7 '.split()][0]
78
```

Or, more explicitly

```
>>> eg = '78 56 78 1 7 '
>>> eg_list = eg.split()
>>> eg_list
['78', '56', '78', '1', '7']
>>> int(eg[0])
7
>>> int(eg_list[0])
78
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to iterate over all of the numbers, as ints:

```
>>> s = '78 56 78 1 7 '
>>> for n in (int(x) for x in s.split()):
...   print(n)
...
78
56
78
1
7
>>>
```